# Wordpress Theme Options Page Not Displaying At All

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I recently was able to resolve an issue with an error I was having before on my theme options page, but now I am having another issue.

When this code is properly include in my functions.php file, it shows up on the sidebar and everything just fine, no errors or anything! But, it does not show any of my options, plus, I don't know if they would work even if they would show, because I can't test it!

Here is the code:

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'where_now_menu' );

function register_mysettings() {
//register our settings
register_setting( 'where-now-settings-group', 'site-logo-url' );
register_setting( 'where-now-settings-group', 'google-analytics' );
}

function where_now_menu() {
add_menu_page( 'Front Door Theme Options', 'Front Door Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'where_now_options', 'where_now_options' );
}

function where_now_options() {
if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
}
}
?>

<?php function where_now_settings_page(){ ?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Front Door Custom Theme Options</h2>
<form method="post" action="theme-options.php">
<?php settings_fields( 'where-now-settings-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'where-now-settings-group' ); ?>
<h3>Site Logo URL</h3><input name="site_logo" type="text" value="<?php echo get_option('site-logo-url'); ?>">
<p>(Hint: A good way to make sure that you will always have this image on your site, upload it to your Wordpress Media section, then grad the URL from the image. Insert that URL to make sure that the location of the image will not change.)</p>
<h3>Google Analytics Tracking Code</h3><input name="analytics_tracking_code" type="textarea" rows="20" cols="20" value="<?php echo get_option('google-analytics'); ?>"></br>
<?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `where_now_options()` does not print anything.. but it's the one added into the menu..

Comment: What should I do to make it print it? I am going off of tutorials here, my PHP experience is passing the CodeCademy PHP course.

Comment: tryin to do something like this? http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/create-a-settings-page-for-your-wordpress-theme/

Comment: I'd really hate to do a table...

Comment: then convert it to tableless, the point is the hooks/functions you include in WP

Comment: Oh ok, so I'm pretty much WAY off. haha